# How to show a "box" around text in HTML tag on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, mouseover

I'm writing a BHO for Internet Explorer where I'm searching for specific words in a web page and encapsulates words found in a HTML-tag, for styling purposes.

I have code to change the style-property when hoovering over the tag, but what I want to do is show a "box" around the word, but I don't want to move the text to any other position than it's original one.

To illustrate, I've made a picture (imagine the word "Overflow!" is in it's own HTML-tag) :

Picture #1 is before, and #2 is when the mouse hoovers the word!

[image]

Can anyone please help me with any suggestions regarding how to solve this problem? Javascript? CSS-styling?

Comment: You should specify what version(s) of IE you're targeting. (Note discussion below about support in 7/8.)

Answer (score 4):

Introduce a  tag around the text you want to highlight, and hook up the onmouseover and onmouseout events to change the CSS class:

```
<span onmouseover="this.className='myMouseOverClass'" onmouseout="this.className=''">Overflow!</span>
```

Then, in your CSS, try something like:

```
.myMouseOverClass
{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-width:2px;
  outline-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `outline` property is much like `border` but is overlaid on other content rather then being part of the box model.

Comment: But this is only supported in IE8+ (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so playing with border and fiddling with margins/padding may be the only way.

Comment: @D.N.: Are you sure? According to w3schools.com it is supported by all the major browsers? http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_outline-style.asp.

Comment: Yes, it says "`Note: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the outline-style property if a !DOCTYPE is specified`" :)

Comment: But from the very same link: "The outline-style property is supported in all major browsers."

Comment: All that means is that you don't agree with W3S' opinion of what counts as a major browser. W3S is, in general, awful — http://w3fools.com/

Comment: In that case, I guess the only way to know for sure is to test it and examine the result for yourself!

Comment: @MikeyCee Why you would not trust documentation *from the people who built IE* is slightly beyond me

Comment: When it comes to browser support of CSS I don't trust anyone. Please don't get me wrong; you may well be right! But when it comes to CSS, right now, the only way to know for sure is to try it out and see what happens. It sucks big time I admit!

Answer (score 0):

I had some modest success in IE7 with

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <span class="boxclass">tempor</span> incididunt`

and

`.boxclass:hover {
border: 3px solid #000000;
margin: -3px;
}`

until I resized within the browser....

Comment: Sorry, IE8. Should ostensibly work in IE7, though. Forgot I upgraded it on this box.